# I want to write a Powershell script which will open CMD as admin and execute desire commands in CMD

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

In my environment we have IIS web config file which is encrypted. We manually Open CMD with admin prompt and run some keys to decrypt that. I tried the same with PS but throwing errors(decryption keys). Here, I would like to automate this using Powershell. Can someone give me a lead?

Comment: Can you please share the code that you have tried and the error which you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

*You can use:* 
Start-Process cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/k dir' -Verb RunAs